# Where does Google chrome save my cookies?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, cookie

I want to import my Google Chrome bookmarks and settings in Brave browser. When Brave ask me the math of the file, I should choose which path?

[image]
[image]

> OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It's not clear to me why the question about a cookie has a selector for bookmarks, these are two entirely distinct pieces of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux the directory is here:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

Comment: Thanks! But This directory has many file in some branch directories. Is there an HTML file to import in Brave?

Comment: The file is ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies